# получение нужных строк из файла

Tags: java

Начал изучать *Java* и передо мной встала такая задача:

Есть текстовый файл `txt`, в нем хранится запись типа `Ф И О`, год рождения, оклад(пример:`Иванов Иван Иванович`, `1973`, `20000`).

Нужно из текстового файла по заданной фамилии(фамилию ввожу в консоль), вывести сведения о сотруднике, подсчитывая средний оклад всех запрошенных сотрудников. То есть - это будет число, которое суммируется по всем сотрудникам( записей может быть несколько, каждая запись начинается с новой строки).

Как подступиться? Использовать регулярки сложно. Перегонять все в чары или делать дела с массивами строк? Прошу помощи.

Comment: Объекты и следом сразу бин файлы, но это имхо.(всмысле менять входной формат)

Answer (score 1):

Создаете класс объектов по записи. Пишите парсер из строки в объект. Потом читаете построчно файл создавая объекты и добавляя их в коллекцию. А дальше делайте все что нужно с вашими объектами.

Например по вашей строке 
`Иванов Иван Иванович, 1973, 20000`

```
public class Employee{
   private String fullName;
   private Integer dob;
   private Double salary;

   public Employee(String fullName,Integer dob, Double salary){
       this.fullName = fullName;
       this.dob = dob;
       this.salary = salary;
   }

   //getters and setters
}
```

Создаете метод который будет парсить вашу строку и создавать из нее объект, можно сделать так:

```
public class EmployeeFactory{

    public static Employee buildEmployee( String strEmployee ){
        String[] arr = strEmployee.split( "," );
        String fullName = arr[0].trim();
        Integer year = Integer.parseInt( arr[1].trim() );
        Double salary = Double.parseDouble( arr[2].trim() );
        return new Employee( fullName, year, salary);
    }

}
```

Далее пишем сервис. задачами которого будут, чтение файла и формирование коллекции сотрудников и поиск сотрудников по заданной фамилии, например так

```
public class EmployeeService{

   /**
    * Загрузка сотрудников из файла
    * @param pathToFile путь к файлу со списком сотрудников
    * @return список сотрудников
    */
   public static List<Employee> loadEmployees( String pathToFile){
       List<Employee> employees = null;
       try( FileReader inputStream = new FileReader( pathToFile );
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( inputStream )){
            employees = readEmployees(bufferedReader);
       }catch( IOException e ){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return employees;
   }

   private static List<Employee> readEmployees(BufferedReader reader) throws  IOException{
       List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
       String strEmployee;
       //Построчно читаем файл и создаем сотрудников
       while((strEmployee = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           employees.add(EmployeeFactory.buildEmployee(strEmployee));
       }
       return employees;
   }


   /**
    * Метод поиска по фамилии в заданном списке
    * @param employees общий список сотрудников в котором ищем
    * @param example фпмилия сотрудника
    * @return список подходящих сотрудников
    */
   public static List<Employee> findEmployeesByExample(List<Employee> employees, String example ){
       List<Employee> res = new ArrayList<>();
       for( Employee emp : employees){
           if(emp.getFullName().startsWith( example )){
               res.add(emp);
           }
       }
       return res;
   }
}
```

А дальше остается только получать данные с консоли, передавать их в сервис и выводить на печать

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    List<Employee> employees = EmployeeService.loadEmployees( "E:/employees.txt" );

    while(true){
        System.out.print( "Введите фамилию:" );
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        String str = scanner.next();

        //для выхода из программы пишем "exit"
        if( str.equals( "exit" ) ){
            return;
        }

        List<Employee> employeeListResult = EmployeeService.findEmployeesByExample( employees, str );
        Double sumSalary = 0.0;
        for( Employee emp : employeeListResult ){
            System.out.println( emp.getFullName() + "\t| " + emp.getSalary() );
            sumSalary += emp.getSalary();
        }

        System.out.println( "=========================================" );
        System.out.println( "сумма по найденным сотрудникам: " + sumSalary );
        System.out.println( "=========================================\n" );

    }
}
```

Если я правильно понял, вы хотели получить что-то вроде этого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее можно посмотреть на здесь https://github.com/jlk191603/ReadEmployeesFromFile